# Build Faild for TFS

Tags: continuous-integration, uwp, azure-devops

[image]

Error:

> C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.103.2\agent\Worker\Tools\nuget.exe
>   failed with return code: 1
>       Packages failed to install Return code: 1
>        Delivery_Analytics\Delivery_Analytics\Delivery_Analytics.csproj (0, 0) 
>       Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'System.Runtime.Handles.dll'
>         C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v14.0\8.2\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets
>   (264, 5)
>       Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System.Runtime.Handles, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.
>
> Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'
>       2016-08-16T12:16:14.5082366Z System.Security.Cryptography.Cng 4.2.0 is not     compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64-aot).
>       2016-08-16T12:16:14.5082366Z System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding 4.0.0 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64-aot).
>       2016-08-16T12:16:14.5092363Z System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives 4.0.0 is not compatible with
>   UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64-aot).
>       2016-08-16T12:16:14.5092363Z System.Collections.NonGeneric 4.0.1 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64-aot).
>       2016-08-16T12:16:14.5092363Z System.Collections.Specialized 4.0.1 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64-aot).
>       2016-08-16T12:16:14.5102364Z System.Private.Uri 4.0.1 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64-aot).
>       2016-08-16T12:16:14.5102364Z System.Net.Requests 4.0.11 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Net.Requests on
>   UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with
>   win10-x64-aot.
>       2016-08-16T12:16:14.5112357Z System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml 4.0.1 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there
>   is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-x64-aot.
>       2016-08-16T12:16:14.5112357Z System.IO.Compression 4.1.1 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.IO.Compression on
>   UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with
>   win10-x64-aot.
>       2016-08-16T12:16:14.5412349Z Generating MSBuild file Delivery_Analytics.nuget. targets.
>       2016-08-16T12:16:14.5432359Z Generating MSBuild file Delivery_Analytics.nuget. props.
>       2016-08-16T12:16:14.5712346Z ##[debug]rc:1
>       2016-08-16T12:16:14.5722353Z ##[debug]success:false
>       2016-08-16T12:16:14.5812337Z ##[error]Error: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.104.1\
>   agent\ Worker\ Tools\nuget.exe failed with return code: 1
>       2016-08-16T12:16:14.5812337Z ##[error]Packages failed to install
>       2016-08-16T12:16:14.5822348Z ##[debug]task result: Failed
>       2016-08-16T12:16:14.5822348Z ##[error]Return code: 1

Comment: Based on my test to build a new UWP app on host agent, it failed, but after I change target and min version of UWP app, it works fine. (Target version: Windows 10 (10.0; Build 10586), Min version: Windows 10 (10.0; Build 10240). So change these version and try again

Comment: I will change target version (Windows 10 (10.0; Build 10586))and min version(Windows 10 (10.0; Build 10240)) but same ERROR is  Reaped.

Comment: did you do build on hosted agent? Does it have the same issue with a new UWP app? Share it on the OneDrive

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am-nsWV0p0KTgRQOOvuO3ZdANPW4

Comment: This above linke is ondrive linke.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my test, changing Microsoft.NetCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform dependency version to 5.1.0, then it works fine. Based on this thread https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/3520, the 5.2.0 is prerelease and isn’t yet supported to be consumed by UWP apps.